# Android Dev: Dialog with multiple screens

Tags: android, dialog

is there any possible way to create a dialog with multiple screens?
That you can click "Next" and get directly forwarded to the next "screen" of the dialog?

My first thought is creating a new Dialog when Clicking the positiveText of the current Dialog.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in your layout for the dialog, use a ViewFlipper and tie its "showNext()" method to a button, tying it to the positive button would cause the dialog to dismiss

Answer (score 0):

Just make a regular old Dialog and populate it entirely with views that you control yourself, just as you would an Activity's views.  No need to try to make an AlertDialog do something other than it was designed for (which is to notify the user or ask a simple question).